# where in history does the significance to silver come into play as a defense against werewolves and vampires\\

Tags: history-of, mythology, werewolf

All myths come from somewhere, so where did the notion that silver affects werewolves come from?

Of wolf-based lore coming from France was there anything during that time that could have contributed to this?